# Need to update GTK+ on Ubuntu (10.04)

Tags: ubuntu, gtk

Trying to build Wireshark from source as there is no Linux installer and I am getting this error when I run the configure script:

```
checking for GTK+ - version >= 2.4.0... no
*** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
configure: error: GTK+ 2.4 or later isn't available, so Wireshark can't be compiled
```

Tried running the following commands with no luck:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Can anyone help me as to how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments.  I've already tried using apt-get but it reports that it couldn't find the package gtk.

Comment: why can't you just do `sudo apt-get install wireshark`?

Comment: Lol, I literally just did that.  Worked a treat.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:
`apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`

Answer (score 0):

The two commands you mention do not state what application you want to update. The actual command is actually
apt-get appname install

In any case I suggest you use the GUI Software Update Manager for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
`sudo apt-get install gtk+2.4`

`sudo apt-get upgrade` actually upgrades just *already installed* packets:

*Packages currently installed with new
           versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no
           circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages
           not already installed retrieved and installed.*
(from man page)

but before `upgrade` you have to issue `update` command in order to invalidate your local information about available packages and to get all latest changes from repos enlisted in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
That's because package system uses it's own local package index to track dependencies when you using `apt-get`.